# How to fetch/read `parquet` files in javascript?

Tags: fetch, svelte, parquet, sveltekit

I've got a simple code from a course on data viz that I'm following. The code example is for fetching a CSV file from a URL and it's from my +page.js file.

I want to do the same(or a local files system fetch) but for parquet file instead of csv and it's proving to be very complicated to find a recent npm package or a code example. Any help to recreate the code below but for the parquet file format would be very appreciated

```
/** @type {import('./$types').PageLoad} */

export async function load({ fetch }) {
    const res = await fetch('https://vda-lab.gitlab.io/datavis-technologies/assets/flights_part.csv', {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'text/csv'
                }})
    let csv_data = await res.text()
    let csv_parsed = Papa.parse(csv_data, {header: true})
    let flights = csv_parsed.data.slice(0,5) // fetches only 5 records.
    

    // console.log(flights)
    console.log(flights)
    return { flights }
}
```

Comment: Don't focus to much on how "recent" a package it is, there is nothing wrong with using older package (or at least check how they work).  If not, you will have to write your own parser for parquet files so looking at these "older packages" would be a good start anyway.

Comment: Not a very helpful comment. The non recent don't help either. There's always some problem with the installed package and something is not recognised.

Comment: If you don't find a good package there is not much more you can do then parse the files yourself, how to do this is far beyond StackOverflow's scope and your best start would be the existing package and adapt them to your need.